# Push to remote on GitHub pointed to a new server IP instead

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've no idea what changed, but I was in for a big surprise when I tried to push to my remote on GitHub and it went to a completely unknown IP instead.

```
[slavik@localhost guardonce]$ git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Connection closed by 192.30.252.128
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Other tests suggest that my local machine's configuration is fine. For example:

```
[slavik@localhost guardonce]$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi slavik81! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

and

```
[slavik@localhost guardonce]$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:slavik81/guardonce.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:slavik81/guardonce.git (push)
```

Looking at my known_hosts, I expected to be speaking to `github.com,204.232.175.90`. So, why aren't I?

Comment: It's a GitHub IP, but I cannot find any info about it at the [GitHub Help Center](https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist).

Comment: The last blog post from GitHub explains it: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18432574/6309)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What has changed is now (August 25th, 2013) explained in "[IP Address Changes](https://github.com/blog/1606-ip-address-changes)":

> We mentioned these new addresses [back in April](https://github.com/blog/1457-upcoming-ip-address-changes) and updated the [Meta API](https://developer.github.com/v3/meta/) to reflect them.
>   Some GitHub services have have already been migrated to the new addresses, including:

```
api.github.com
gist.github.com
ssh.github.com
```

> Our next step is to begin using these IP addresses for the main GitHub site, so we're reminding everyone about this change.
>   There are a few gotchas that might affect some people:
>
> - If you have explicit firewall rules in place that allow access to GitHub from your network, you'll want to make sure that all of the IP ranges listed in this article are included.
> - If you have an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file that points `github.com` at a specific IP address, you should remove it and instead rely on DNS to give you the most accurate set of addresses.
> - If you are accessing your repositories over the SSH protocol, you will receive a warning message each time your client connects to a new IP address for `github.com`.
>     As long as the IP address from the warning is in the range of IP addresses in the previously mentioned Help page, you shouldn't be concerned.
>     Specifically, the new addresses that are being added this time are in the range from 192.30.252.0 to 192.30.255.255.
>     The warning message looks like this:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '$IP' to the list of known hosts.
```

Answer (score 4):

check existing remote url

```
git config remote.origin.url
```

if it is not correct you can change it by:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:slavik81/guardonce.git
```

Comment: I get `git@github.com:slavik81/guardonce.git` as the output, which seems fine. Redoing the push has lead me to success... Which is bizarre.

Comment: This was a useful answer and satisfied me at the time, but VonC more thoroughly solved my mystery. Sorry for the unaccept.

Comment: @Slavik81 it's no problem. good answers must be accepted so that it will be easier to find to other people.

Answer (score 1):

It's a github server in California

```
$ git config remote.origin.url
git@github.com:blah/foo
$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.252.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.30.252.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=63.6 ms
```

http://en.utrace.de/ip-address/192.30.252.128

Edit:
They've been under a heavy DDoS attack in the last few days so they probably did this to help fight it.

Answer (score 0):

The url of git pushes are listed in config folder. Look for .git folder in you application and then open the config file inside it.

```
$ cat config
```

`[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:******/******.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "sprint_1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/sprint_1`

Checkout the url for remote "origin", it shows the remote present url. You can make changes here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying with `capistrano` gem, it clones the repo in `deploy_dir/shared/cached-copy` on the server.

Simply remove the `deploy_dir/shared/cached-copy` directory.

`$ rm -rf deploy_dir/shared/cached-copy`

Then deploy again.